# Display weather information in the Mavericks notification center?

Tags: macos, notifications

The weather display in the notification center is a great feature in iOS, and I would love to have it on my mac as well. Is there a technique or app that allows this?

Googling for the answer to this question has not turned up much, although there are suggestions that one might be able to kludge something together using Growl.

Comment: What's wrong with using the Weather widget in Dashboard?

Comment: I would enjoy this myself. I like the Notification Center because I'm used to that on iOS 7.

Comment: As of late December 2013, Apple does not provide a public API for apps to put themselves into Notification Center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X Yosemite's Notification Center comes with a Weather widget preinstalled.

[image]

Additional locations can be added to the widget:

[image]

Comment: … since Yosemite is unreleased, would you say this a "good" answer? I don't want to nag, I'm actually curious considering *questions* about unreleased software are considered "not ok" what the consensus is about *answers*.

Comment: @Asmus In my opinion certain features of pre-release software are fine for answers, depending on its publicity and apparent 'final' appearance and functionality. Feel free to raise this on [meta] for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try hooking up something using [IFTTT for getting some alerts with Boxcar](https://ifttt.com/boxcar) and then launch the notifications using a shell script to drive the notifications on OSX like [this example](https://github.com/jedda/OSX-Monitoring-Tools/blob/master/notify_by_boxcar.sh) does for monitoring services.

Answer (score -2):

As far as i know you can only get it on mavericks by jailbreaking it my be different for mavericks by now but last time i checked there was no way so i assume you would need to jailbreak. But on yosemite it comes pre-installed. (not the jailbreak) Hope this helps

Comment: You're talking about jailbreaking a Mac?

Comment: What do you mean by "jailbreaking Mavericks"? In OS X on Macs, you can get root access by default, without exploiting anything. Jailbreaking phones means getting root access. I don't see how this could help with the question at all.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you could 'jailbreak' a computer...